# What is the effect of temperature on the spring constant of a steel spring?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, particle-physics, experimental-physics, spring

I'm doing a research on how temperature changes spring constant and the physics behind this change. I would really appreciate this. Thank you so much.

Comment: The spring constant depends on properties of the material in which the spring is made. The exact property depends on the geometry of the spring. For a coil spring, the important property is the shear modulus. For a rod in compression, that would be Young's modulus. That should get you started as there is a lot on shear modulus vs temperature information. You can look the coil spring and shear modulus pages on Wikipedia for more info and go from there.

Comment: What kind of temperature changes are you considering? I would imagine a few degrees change would do little to the spring constant, but many dozens of degrees change would likely do something.